# How to change background of circles in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator

How to change background of viewpager circles here is screen [image]

I want to make above blue color should display as background for the viewpager indicator also ,How can change background.here is my xml for the viewpager indicator

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

programmatically you can call `setPageColor`, which takes a color as parameter, on the `CirclePageIndicator` instance, or in the xml you can set the `pageColor` attribute

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
    xmlns:whatever="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    whatever:pageColor="#FFFF0000"
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
```

Comment: Background using image not color and i want above image should visible for viewpagerindicator background